# .war on tomcat docker container controller not found

Tags: java, docker, tomcat, servlets, war

I've a web app application written in java that expose some servlet. In the same application there is an index.html which is connected with other pages.
I deployed the war file, and when I run the server by using IntelliJ everything works properly. I see the index file exposed on localhost:8080/Project30

[image]

But when i try to run the war inside a docker container, i cannot reach servlets. I'm able to get the page of index.html, but when i try to access to some urls exposed as servlet i got 404.

This is the code for docker compose

```
  version: "3.9" #version of docker-compose
  services:
    mysql:
      container_name: mysql
      image: mysql
      ports:
      - "3307:3306"
      environment:
        - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=admin                    #default password of the MySQL container
      volumes:
        - ./data:/var/lib/mysql                         #database data volume
        - ./src/main/db:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d  #database files called when the container is built and started for the first time
    web:
      container_name: tomcat
      build: .
      ports:
        - "8080:8080"
```

and this is the docker file

```
FROM maven:3.6.3 AS build

# Copy pom.xml to the image
COPY pom.xml /home/app/pom.xml
RUN mvn -f /home/app/pom.xml verify clean --fail-never

# Copy the source code
COPY src /home/app/src
RUN mvn -f /home/app/pom.xml package

#FROM tomcat:latest
FROM tomcat:8.0-alpine

LABEL maintainer="emme"
COPY --from=build /home/app/target/Project30.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/
EXPOSE 8080

CMD ["catalina.sh", "run"]
```

War is deployed in right way, as these are the file in container
[image]

Tomcat is running in properly way, as if i go on localhost:8080 i see tomcat admin page.
I don't understand what i'm doing wrongly